# How to tell if an ssh ControlMaster connection is in use

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, tunneling, daemon

I'd like to use `ssh`'s [ControlMaster](http://www.anchor.com.au/blog/2010/02/ssh-controlmaster-the-good-the-bad-the-ugly/) feature to share connections for speed increases. I'm trying to script it so that I can start/restart/stop a number of connections to different hosts.

How can I determine whether any of these connections are in use? If I kill them when an ssh session is open, it gets closed

My restart script would ideally look like (pseudo-script) - the stop script would be equivalent without the ssh command at the bottom:

```
for HOST in $HOST_LIST
  do
    MASTER_PID=`find_master_pid $HOST`
    if $MASTER_PID
      then
        if `find_child_pid`
          echo Connection to $HOST in use: not terminating
        else
          kill -SIGHUP $MASTER_PID
        fi
    ssh -TMNf $HOST
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could simply use

```
ssh -o ControlPath=$socket -O check 'unused-hostname'
```

for each $socket you've open (easy if you keep them in a single directory).

This returns 255 if the check fails (connection not active anymore), an other value if it pass.
You may need to specify the hostname too, but nothing that an awk on $socket won't give you :)

Comment: That's much simpler for seeing if the existing connection is open; it doesn't tell me if it is actually being used, but I guess that isn't so important... (and I have the method below)

Comment: I found I had to pass some argument at the end, otherwise I got an error. ```ssh -o ControlPath=8dcbe9e120884b5f25709f25ef2f0863ac3301d4 -O check ```*""*```
Master running (pid=25512)```

but without it, it replies with usage;   

```usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]   
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]``` (this is on fedora f27 (OpenSSH_7.6p1, OpenSSL 1.1.0g-fips  2 Nov 2017)

Comment: The problem with this is it will **hang forever** in some cases, even with `ConnectTimeout` options. For example, if I have a control socket "open" to `some_host` over a network route that no longer exists, `ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 -O check some_host` hangs forever. OpenSSH itself appears to have no way to detect/recover from this: I have to use `timeout 5 ssh -O check some_host`.

Answer (score 3):

*@Renik's answer didn't work for me. See below for what did.*

---

This works for me using just the socket file for the control master:

```
$ ssh -o ControlPath=~/.ssh/<controlfile> -O check <bogus arg>
```

**NOTE:** You can also use `ssh -S ~/.ssh/<controlfile> ...` as well, which is a bit shorter form of the above.

#### Example

Here's an example where I've already established a connection to a remote server:

```
$ ssh -S ~/.ssh/master-57db26a0499dfd881986e23a2e4dd5c5c63e26c2 -O check blah
Master running (pid=89228)
$
```

And with it disconnected:

```
$ ssh -S ~/.ssh/master-66496a62823573e4760469df70e57ce4c15afd74 -O check blah
Control socket connect(/Users/user1/.ssh/master-66496a62823573e4760469df70e57ce4c15afd74): No such file or directory
$
```

If it were still connected, this would force it to exit immediately:

```
$ ssh -S ~/.ssh/master-66496a62823573e4760469df70e57ce4c15afd74 -O exit blah
Exit request sent.
$
```

It's unclear to me, but it would appear to potentially be a bug in `ssh`  that it requires an additional argument at the end, even though `blah` is meaningless in the context of the switches I'm using.

Without it gives me this:

```
$ ssh -S ~/.ssh/master-57db26a0499dfd881986e23a2e4dd5c5c63e26c2 -O check
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
           [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-Q cipher | cipher-auth | mac | kex | key]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] [user@]hostname [command]
```

#### Version info

*OSX*

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
```

*CentOS 7.x*

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
```

I confirmed that on both of these versions, the need for the additional bogus argument was required.

#### References

- [How to close (kill) ssh ControlMaster connections manually](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24005/how-to-close-kill-ssh-controlmaster-connections-manually)
- [How to exit OpenSSH control master process without using lsof or fuser?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459450/how-to-exit-openssh-control-master-process-without-using-lsof-or-fuser#459473)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a utility that eases management of SSH ControlMaster connections. It's called **`cmc`**:
[TimidRobot/cmc: ControlMaster Controller - Eases management of SSH ControlMaster connections](https://github.com/TimidRobot/cmc).

Answer (score 0):

My current approach is to use `lsof` to find the Unix sockets. If I know the target filename specified by `ControlPath` I can search for the master process like this:

```
function find_master_pid() {
  lsof -a -U -u $USER -c ssh | grep $CM_DIR/$RUSER@$HOST | sed 's/^ssh *//' | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort -u
}
```

This will then give me the `PID` (unfortunately, giving the filename of the unix socket file directly to `lsof` doesn't work otherwise I could just ask it to output me the `pid` with `-f`; hence the `sed` and `cut`)

Searching for the child process is more tricky. The master process opens a new socket for each child process, connected to the standard file. The child process contains a socket simply marked `socket`. However, the inode returned by `lsof` is one less than the corresponding master process socket. So the following finds child processes that are connected to the master process (this needs the `$MASTER_PID` to check against)

```
function find_child_pid() {
  for CHILD_PID in `lsof -a -U -u $USER -c ssh | grep socket | sed 's/^ssh *//' | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort -u`
    do
      CHECK_PID=0
      for NODE in `lsof -a -U -u $USER -p $CHILD_PID -F i | grep ^i | sed 's/i//'`
        do
          MASTER_NODE=$((NODE+1))
          CHECK_PID=`lsof -a -U -u $USER -p $MASTER_PID | grep $MASTER_NODE | wc -l`
          [[ $CHECK_PID == 1 ]] && echo $CHILD_PID
        done
    done
}
```