# Close/kill a ssh local port forwarding connection | No ControlPath specified for "-O" command error

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have a sshfs/fuse mounted folder and 2 local port forwarding in the background.

From this post:

[How to clear local ssh port for forwarding to remote?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1082990/how-to-clear-local-ssh-port-for-forwarding-to-remote)

With this command i see only my mounted sshfs/fuse folder not the local port forwarding connection.

`ps -af |grep [s]sh`

See the local port forwarding connection process with:

`ps -x |grep "[s]sh -fN"`

or from this post:

[Finding the process that is using a certain port in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/42843/finding-the-process-that-is-using-a-certain-port-in-linux)

`lsof -i tcp:[PORT]`

I can kill 1 of the process for the local port forwarding connection with:

`kill <id>`

When i try to close/kill the process with:

`ssh -O cancel -L [PORT]:[IP]:[PORT] [IP]`

I receive error a msg like:

`No ControlPath specified for "-O" command`

From this post:

[How do I remove an SSH forwarded port](https://superuser.com/questions/87014/how-do-i-remove-an-ssh-forwarded-port)

This commands won't work too:

`pkill -f "ssh -f -N [REMOTE_IP]"`

and

`ssh -O exit [REMOTE_IP]`

From this post:

[How to delete local ssh tunnel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51456524/how-to-delete-local-ssh-tunnel)

and

`ssh -o ControlPath=$socket -O check`

i receive

`command-line line 0: Missing argument.`

From post:

[How to tell if an ssh ControlMaster connection is in use](https://serverfault.com/questions/211213/how-to-tell-if-an-ssh-controlmaster-connection-is-in-use)

I wanna close/kill a given connection with a port and not all, if i got as an example 3 connections on a host with diff ports, with a ssh command not with kill process like:

`ssh -O cancel -L ....`

or an other ssh command.

How can i fit this and where is my error with?

`ssh -O cancel -L [PORT]:[IP]:[PORT] [IP]`

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you need to identify the control path when cancelling port forwarding.

So when you create the port forwarding you would specify a control path such as /tmp/mysshcontrolpath, i.e.

```
ssh -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath=/tmp/mysshcontrolpath -N -R [PORT]:[IP]:[PORT] [IP]
```

... and then when you want to stop the port forwarding you would use exactly the same thing, but with the addition of "-O exit", i.e.

```
ssh -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath=/tmp/mysshcontrolpath -O exit -N -R [PORT]:[IP]:[PORT] [IP]
```

... and then you should get the response "Exit request sent".

Additionally I always use the ExitOnForwardFailure option when creating port forwarding so that it doesn't hang if the attempt fails, i.e.

```
ssh -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath=/tmp/mysshcontrolpath -N -R [PORT]:[IP]:[PORT] [IP]
```

I understand that some flavours of Linux come with a control path pre-specified in a ~/.ssh/config file, so that one doesn't need to specify a control path when creating port forwarding. You can create this config file in any version of Linux, as discussed [here](https://docs.rackspace.com/blog/speeding-up-ssh-session-creation/#:%7E:text=as%20text%20editing.-,ControlPath%20%7E%2F.ssh%2Fsockets%2F%25r%40%25h%2D%25p,ssh%2Fsockets%20.).

Hope this gives you some clues to help solve your problem...

Answer (score 2):

If you know the port of the Process (here 8080) simply use

`kill $(lsof -t -i:8080)`

where

`lsof -i:8080`

gives you all PIDs